# R. Get_sentiments() Error - menu() cannot be used interactively?

Tags: r, text

I am a novice to R, and I am learning from the Text Mining with R text. I am trying to invoke the following lines. Even though I follow the text, I still get an unpredicted error? I appreciate any help, thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
library(textdata)

nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% filter(sentiment == "joy")
```

Error in menu(choices = c("Yes", "No"), title= title): menu() cannot be used non-interactively

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked well, you can share your session information mine is:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] textdata_0.3.0 tidytext_0.2.2 tidyr_1.0.0    dplyr_0.8.3   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.10   magrittr_1.5     
 [4] rappdirs_0.3.1    hms_0.5.0         tidyselect_0.2.5 
 [7] lattice_0.20-38   R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.4.0      
[10] tools_3.6.0       grid_3.6.0        janeaustenr_0.1.5
[13] assertthat_0.2.1  tibble_2.1.3      lifecycle_0.1.0  
[16] crayon_1.3.4      Matrix_1.2-17     readr_1.3.1      
[19] purrr_0.3.2       fs_1.3.1          vctrs_0.2.0      
[22] tokenizers_0.2.1  SnowballC_0.6.0   zeallot_0.1.0    
[25] glue_1.3.1        stringi_1.4.3     compiler_3.6.0   
[28] pillar_1.4.1      generics_0.0.2    backports_1.1.4  
[31] pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine.  Did you type the name of the object after you assigned it?  It won't print or show an output unless you tell r to display the object or to print() the object.  The output is a tibble and its dimension is 689 x 2.

```
nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% filter(sentiment == "joy")
nrc_joy
```

Just click the up arrow next to this answer if it works for you.

Good luck.